# How to use react-select without options list?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'd like to allow the user to type in words and press enter/tab to submit multiple options. This functionality is clearly possible as seen in the last example on [this page](https://react-select.com/creatable) (titled "Multi-select text input"). However, when I press enter/tab the values don't show up. If I enable the menu and use the "Create new" option then it works fine. Also, if I give the component the options prop, that works fine.

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

export type OptionType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  __isNew__?: boolean;
};
export type Value = ValueType<OptionType>;
export type Values = Array<Value>;

export const createOption = (value: string, label?: string): OptionType => ({
  value,
  label: label ? label : value
});

interface ListTextFieldProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, WithTheme {
  values: Values;
  setValues: (values: Values) => void;
  label?: string;
}


const ListTextField: React.FC<ListTextFieldProps> = props => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const selectStyles = {
    input: (base: any) => ({
      ...base,
      color: props.theme.palette.text.primary,
      '& input': {
        font: 'inherit'
      }
    })
  };

  const handleInputChange = (value: string, meta: InputActionMeta) => {
    if (meta.action === 'input-change') {
      setInputValue(value);
    }
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (event: any) => {
    if (!inputValue) return;
    if (['Enter', 'Tab'].includes(event.key)) {
      console.log(inputValue)
      handleValueChange([...props.values, createOption(inputValue.trim())])
      setInputValue('');
    }
  }

  const handleValueChange = (values?: Value | Values | null) => {
    console.log(values)
    if (Array.isArray(values)) {
      props.setValues(values);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unexpected type passed to ReactSelect onChange handler')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={props.classes.root}>
        <CreatableSelect
          classes={props.classes}
          inputValue={inputValue}
          onInputChange={handleInputChange}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          styles={selectStyles}
          textFieldProps={{
            label: props.label ? props.label : undefined,
            InputLabelProps: {
              shrink: true
            }
          }}
          menuIsOpen={false}
          values={props.values}
          onChange={handleValueChange}
          isMulti
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Take a look at `react-typeahead`, should be what you're looking for https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/

Answer (score 2):

You provided `values` prop to Select component. It should be `value`.